# Do relationships between tables need to have descriptions?

Tags: mysql, database, relational

Do table associations need to have roles. I find this difficult to understand for example if there is a product table and an inventory table and A row in the product table is associated with many rows in an inventory table.(eg. each copy of a particular product has a unique serial number which is a foreign key referencing a column in the inventory table)can be associated with one or (likely) more rows in another table

I find this kind of relationship difficult to describe. If it were inverted you could say a product is held in 1 and only 1 inventory and an inventory contains 1 to many products.

I was having trouble understanding a similar problem as described above until I found the various definitions for the relationships on this page

http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9922/~/understanding-and-creating-many-to-many-relationships-in-filemaker-pro

Maybe I am thinking about it the wrong way

Comment: What information modeling method are you to use?

Comment: I am using an er diagram in sql workbench with a top down approach(not sure if that answers your question I'm a beginner in relation to databases)

Comment: Re "each copy of a particular product has a unique serial number which is a foreign key referencing a column in the inventory table" You are confusing copies identified by serial #s with products identified by product #s. An inventory item *is* a particular copy. What you mean is that there is a particular product # in the  product table which multiple inventory table rows have, each with the serial # of the inventory item/copy that is that kind of product. So you have a FK on product # from inventory to products. Why would both tables have serial #?

Answer (score 1):

Read about Chen's ERM (Entity-Relationship Model) method/diagrams: Entities are boxes (& entity type tables), relation(ship) types are diamonds (& association tables), participations of entity types are lines from diamond to box (& FKs) and properties (non-entity "participants" or attributes) are ovals on lines. This makes it clear what is a relation(ship)/table and what is a participation/FK. Then some ER variants misuse the term "relationship" for FK and leave out diamonds so it's not so clear what the relation(ship)s and participations are. (See wikipedia Entity-relationship model.) You use the term "role", which is used in Object-Role Modeling for participation (by entity or property). It is the truest to the relational model and can be mapped to ER and ER variant methods. (ER has the problem of artificial distinctions. There is really no difference between an entity, relationship or property, and every table superkey corresponds to an "entity".)